# mapbox : How to show all the specified coordinates as a custom icons on the map at once

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a dynamic array of coordinates. I want to adjust the Mapbox to show all the coordinates within the array as a custom icon on the map.

I have tried flyTo, JumpTo, ZoomTo functions of the Mapbox. but it is zooming to only a single coordinate value.
I want to show all the coordinates within the array on the Map at once.

Example:
if my array has 10 coordinates, Mapbox should adjust to show all the 10 coordinates as a custom icon on the map.
if my array has 100 coordinates then all 100 custom icons I want to see on the map.

I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Please refer to this page https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to rephrase your question to make it meet the standards of a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/zoomto-linestring/) in our Mapbox GL JS documentation shows how to fit a map to the bounds of a `LineString`. As explained in further detail in the inline comments of the linked example, this same technique of using the [`LatLngBounds#extend` method](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/geography/#lnglatbounds#extend) to extend the bounds to include a given `LngLatLike` can be used to wrap each coordinate pair in your array with the `extend` method. This will have the effect of including each point in your array in the `bounds` passed to [`Map#fitBounds`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#fitbounds), which will pan and zoom the map to contain the visible area including all points in your array.

That is, your code will look something like:

```
var coordinatesArray = [/* an array with your coordinates to display */];

var bounds = coordinatesArray.reduce(function(bounds, coord) {
  return bounds.extend(coord);
}, new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds(coordinatesArrray[0], coordinatesArrray[0]));

map.fitBounds(bounds, { padding: 20 });
```